# What proof that a claim exists is needed to post a question?

Tags: discussion

What proof, if any, do I need to provide that a claim exists.

For instance, what if I hear from a friend that the moon is made of cheese? Can my question just indicate that I heard it from a friend? Do I need a link to a source or an infographic? Does it matter more or less if the claim is well known compared to a claim that is obscure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "well known" claims, you do not need to do anything. We will accept them as automatically notable.

For other claims you need to show that many people believe the claim to be true:

- Ideally, by showing the claim is commonly found on the internet being proposed by people that believe it is true.
- Less ideally, by arguing that the claim has appeared in the major-distribution media. This still needs to show that many people believing the claim is true: a minor, local or specific-interest newspaper claiming something unimportant or hard to believe would not show notability.
- Even less ideally, by arguing that the claim has been repeated by a famous or influential person. Of all the claims a famous person makes, we much prefer the ones which get wide publicity on the media and that a lot of people end up repeating. Claims that no one else repeats or picks up, might well not be notable.